# how to use the unix "find" command to find all the cpp and h files?

Tags: unix, find

I know that to find all the `.h` files I need to use:

```
find . -name "*.h"
```

but how to find all the `.h` AND `.cpp` files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unix find: multiple file types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190565/unix-find-multiple-file-types)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
find . -name \*.h -print -o -name \*.cpp -print
```

or

```
find . \( -name \*.h -o -name \*.cpp \) -print
```

Comment: Has something changed with `find` in the last couple of years? I can’t get this to work in either Ubuntu 9.10 or OS X 10.6. It finds the `.cpp` files but not the `.h` files. Example: https://gist.github.com/783687

Comment: Try `find . -name \*.h -print -o -name \*.cpp -print`

Comment: Alternatively, to enable better code reuse: `find . \( -name '*.h' -o -name '*.cpp' \) -print`

Answer (score 14):

```
find -name "*.h" -or -name "*.cpp"
```

(edited to protect the asterisks which were interpreted as formatting)

Comment: This only returns files whose names are exactly '.h' or '.cpp'. A wildcard is required to work as desired:

    find -name "*.h" -or -name "*.cpp"

Comment: `-or` is a GNUism. But `-o` is standard (POSIX).

Comment: I can confirm that on Ubuntu the following is working: `find ./ -name "*.h" -o -name "*.c*"` (I'm not only looking for cpp files (C++) but also for cs ones (C#) :-) )

Answer (score 7):

[Paul Tomblin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277999/how-to-use-the-unix-find-command-to-find-all-the-cpp-and-h-files#278002)   Has Already provided a terrific answer, but I thought I saw a pattern in what you were doing.

Chances are you'll be using find to generate a file list to process with grep one day, and for such task there exists a much more user friendly tool, [Ack](http://petdance.com/ack/)

Works on any system that supports perl, and searching through all C++ related files in a directory recursively for a given string is as simple as

```
ack "int\s+foo" --cpp
```

`"--cpp"` by default matches `.cpp .cc .cxx .m .hpp .hh .h .hxx` files

(It also skips repository dirs by default so wont match on files that happen to look like files in them.)

Answer (score 7):

A short, clear way to do it with `find` is:

```
find . -regex '.*\.\(cpp\|h\)'
```

From the man page for `-regex`: "This is a match on the whole path, not a search." Hence the need to prefix with `.*` to match the beginning of the path `./dir1/dir2/...` before the filename.

Answer (score 3):

```
find . -regex ".*\.[cChH]\(pp\)?" -print
```

This tested fine for me in cygwin.

Comment: That will also find files with extension `c`, `Cpp`, `Hpp`, which are either not cpp files, nor common extensions. Also, you did not escape the last dot properly, which means you will also math files named e.g. `xcpp` or `.C`. You introduced several problems by not mastering regular expressions and find properly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `find` in this short form:

```
find \( -name '*.cpp' -o -name '*.h' \) -print
```

`-print` can be omitted. Using `-o` just between expressions is especially useful when you want to find multiple types of files and do one same job (let's say calculating md5sum).