# Unix find: multiple file types

Tags: unix, find

I want to run find -name with multiple file types.
Eg.

```
 find -name *.h,*.cpp
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Turns out, this question has been asked before ... for same example of `*.h` and `*.cpp`! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277999/how-to-use-the-unix-find-command-to-find-all-the-cpp-and-h-files

Answer (score 100, accepted):

```
$ find . -name '*.h' -o -name '*.cpp'
```

To find this information in the `man` page, type `man find` and the search for operators by typing `/OPERATORS` and hit enter.

The `.` isn't strictly necessary with GNU find, but is necessary in Unix. The quotes are important in either case, and leaving them out will cause errors if files of those types appear in the current directory.

On some systems (such as Cygwin), parentheses are necessary to make the set of extensions inclusive:

```
$ find . \( -name '*.h' -o -name '*.cpp' \)
```

Comment: The parenthesis should not be necessary, but quoting `*.h` and `*.cpp` might be.

Comment: @JoachimSauer thanks, I was about to return and add quotes, didn't realize the parenthesis weren't necessary.

Comment: Since the OP mention UNIX, the '.' is _strictly_ necessary. GNU find doesn't require it

Comment: @JoachimSauer On my system I do need parenthesis... are there differences between different linux distros?

Comment: On my Cygwin, if I use the example from Eric it runs fine. 
But if I add a "-print" at the end it only uses the last -name filter. 
When I add the parenthesis it works with the -print option. Joachim I think it may be the same for you.

Comment: For me on Ubuntu it appears that the parenthesis are necessary as soon as I want it to be piped e.g. to xargs. Without it, it will still *run but only use the last extension* I mention.

Comment: What is the use of "-o" ?

Comment: @Priyal `-o` is for "or"

Answer (score 20):

Thats what I use

```
find . \( -name "*.h" -o -name "*.cpp" \) -print
```

Comment: Unless you feel that adding `-print` is new and useful information, it would be better to upvote one of the existing answers rather than adding duplication.

Comment: The parantheses are important.

Comment: Interesting... your solution works for me... if I don't use parentheses it fails and only finds the second type of file. +1!

Answer (score 13):

You can also use the `-regex` utility:

`find -E . -iregex ".*\.(js|jsx|html|htm)"`

Remember that the regex looks at the full absolute path:

For an explanation of that regex with test cases check out: https://regex101.com/r/oY1vL2/1

`-E`(as a flag BEFORE the path) enables extended (modern) regular expressions.

This is for BSD `find` (Mac OSX 10.10.5)

Answer (score 12):

```
find . -name "*.h" -or -name "*.cpp"
```

works for me.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know you could use `-or`, I've only seen `-o`. Works, and easy to remember.

Comment: Note that not all versions of `find` (e.g. here on Solaris) support `-or` instead of `-o`

Answer (score 8):

```
find . -name '*.h' -o -name '*.cc'`
```

works for searching files.

```
find . \( -name '*.h' -o -name '*.cc' \)`
```

works for executing commands on them

```
find . \( -name '*.h' -o -name '*.cc' \) -exec egrep "#include" {} \; -print | egrep "^\."
```

Comment: Thanks for the last example, it wasn't obvious that the `\( ... \)` are needed once you pass it to e.g. `xargs`. Without braces the command was always only executed on the last extension.

Answer (score 6):

That's what I use.I strongly recommend the "-regextype posix-extended" argument.

```
find . -type f -iname "*.log" -o -iname "*.gz" 
find . -type f \( -name "*.gz" -o -name "*.log" \)
find . -type f -regex '.*\(\.gz\|\.log\)'
find . -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*.(log|gz)'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find ./ -name *.csv -o \\-name *.txt|xargs grep -i new
```